# python while loop quit variable

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to figure out how to do quit variable in a `while` loop. I am learning python, so this is new.

Should I start with

```
variable1
variable2

print("Press enter to continue, or type "quit" then press enter to stop")

while "quit"!="quit"

       variable1=input("enter input")
       variable2=input("enter input")
```

i am missing a huge gap of information. (i feel)

```
sName=input("Please enter your name: ")
iNum=int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
dNum=float(input("Please enter a decimal number: "))
print("Name:",sName)
print("Value of iNum:",iNum)
print("Value of dNum:",dNum)

sName=" "
iNum=" "
dNum=" "

print("Press enter to continue, or type "Q" then press enter to stop")

while "Q"!=quit 
   sName=input("enter input")
   iNum=input("enter input")
   dNum=input("enter input")
```

as you can see, i have no idea what i am doing -_-

Comment: Please post code that you have actually tried running, as well as what you expected to get as output, and what you actually got as output. **This code is not even syntactically valid**, so it doesn't seem to fit that description.

Comment: [sName=input("Please enter your name: ")
iNum=int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
dNum=float(input("Please enter a decimal number: "))
print("Name:",sName)
print("Value of iNum:",iNum)
print("Value of dNum:",dNum)

sName=" "
iNum=" "
dNum=" "

print("Press enter to continue, or type "Q" then press enter to stop")

while "Q"!=quit 
       sName=input("enter input")
       iNum=input("enter input")
       dNum=input("enter input")]

Comment: @user3758438 add code to your question - it will be more readable.

Comment: I dont know why it posted like it did. I can not figure out how to fix it.

Comment: @user3758438 add code to your question - not to comments

Comment: Click on "edit", on the left between the question and the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
quit = ''

while quit.lower() != 'quit':
   print( "Press enter to continue, or type 'quit' then press enter to stop" )
   quit = input("enter input: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as alternative:

```
while True:
    q = raw_input("Please enter 'quit' to stop:")
    if q.strip() == 'quit':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using input() as a wrapper function for a prompt of this nature because it wraps raw_input in eval() python which is very unsafe for most applications.  raw_input() is likely what you're after.

With that in mind you could use something like this:

```
input_var = ''
while input_var != 'quit':
    input_var = raw_input('Enter quit to quit: ')
```

And it should get you what you're after.  You can also use a break statement as suggested earlier.

If you're writing an actual command prompt, I'd recommend the excellent cmd library.